# Allow users to plot points on a Google Map (With PHP/Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps

I want to be able to show a map of an area, and allow people to click on the map to add some information to the point they click.

I know how to set up a Google map, and show points on the map from info stored in a database. I just don't know how to allow someone to add a point to the map.

I need to know how to determine when the user clicks on the map, and get the coordinates of the point they clicked on. I also need to allow them to enter some information about the point that they clicked, and then store all of this information in the DB.

Ideally this would be done via ajax, however I'd even go for a solution where once they click the map they are taken to a new page with a form to fill in the info, and the coordinates already filled in based on the point that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attach a function to the click event of the map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventListeners). This function will be passed the coordinates of the click.  From there you have many options. As long as you pass along the click coordinates you'll be able to add them to the database.

Comment: Ok, that looks pretty straight forward. Thanks for your help.